# Is there an adjective for the word "dictionary"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective for the word "dictionary"?

For example, the adjective for "book" is "bibliographical"; and "literature", "literary".

> A bibliophile may give you a literary definition; a logophile may give you a [dictionary] definition.

I know "dictionary" on its own can fit, but I would like to find an actual adjective.

The closest word I can think of is one that I have made up: "dictionarial".

**Update:** [I've had a quick look on OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52322), and it seems "dictionarial" does seem to be a word. I'm still a bit uncomfortable about it, however. Is it a well-recognised word?

Comment: Maybe *sanctioned*, *canonical*, *official*, etc.

Comment: Perhaps "lexical" (relating to words or vocabulary) or "encyclopedic" (relating to all branches of knowledge). Also "terminological".

Comment: @Graffito I like your suggestion of "lexical". I might use that if I can't get an adjective for "dictionary".

Comment: grammar?  A grammatician may give you a dictionary.

Comment: _Dictionary definition_ is such a set phrase that, really, I think you're only doing yourself a disservice by eschewing it in favour of an obscure adjective. _Dictionarial_ would of course be readily understood, but it ain't pretty.

Answer (score 3):

Would [*lexicographical*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lexicography?q=lexicographical) work?

Oxford Dictionaries Online has a few examples.

Comment: +1 I took the liberty of creating a link to the Oxford Dictionaries Online page.

Answer (score 0):

The only adjectival use which the OED quotes is from 1598:

> 1596   T. Nashe Haue with you to Saffron-Walden sig. N4 v,   **To so
>   Dictionarie a custome** it was grown with him, that..he would extempore
>   in that kinde of verse runne vppon mens hearts and womens hearts all
>   the night long.

But interestingly, and perhaps infuriatingly its antithesis has a clear adjectival form, namely *dictionaryless* - listed in the OED.

Comment: Sorry, could you please bold where the adjectival usage is? I'm not sure if it's just me, but the OED can look a bit messy.